# ANR in an IntentService with its own process

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I have an IntentService with its own process, right like that:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service 
    android:name="com.app.services.UpdateDatabaseService"
    android:process=":updateDatabaseService"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

Then when IntentService is running, it create two threads. One of the task that a thread is a long task (more than 1 min). And I get an ANR issue.

```
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): ANR in com.app:FooService
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): Reason: Executing service com.app/.services.FooService
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): Load: 1.08 / 0.48 / 0.21
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): CPU usage from 13433ms to 1122ms ago:
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   92% 1375/com.emanga:updateMangaDatabase: 87% user + 5.7% kernel / faults: 5740 minor
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   0.4% 148/system_server: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 13 minor
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   0.2% 45/adbd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   0.1% 758/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   0% 266/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): 93% TOTAL: 87% user + 6.2% kernel + 0% irq
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148): CPU usage from 1804ms to 2442ms later:
10-24 18:51:27.923: E/ActivityManager(148):   70% 1375/com.emanga:updateMangaDatabase: 65% user + 4.9% kernel / faults: 123 minor
```

At no time the UI is blocked. So if the service is in a separate process (not UI Thread) why I get this error?

**EDIT 1:**

I changed IntentService to Service but I get same issue yet. I will try explain what I want get. The architecture of my app has activities that shows data recovered from a database using Loaders. If database has not the asked data, then it will request to a service that will recover data from internet (the service manages internet requests, it parses some html, updates the database with the new data and at the end the service notifies about the changes)

This service has its own process because although the service catch the exceptions that could be to occur, this way the app is robuster against internet or parser failures (the app won't crash)

The Loaders's aim is to get data from database, and the service's aim is to get data from internet and to update the database. The communication between Loaders and Services is only for notify changes or requests.

Finally this Service has a queue of tasks and an executor that runs the tasks.

```
public class UpdateDatabaseService extends Service {

    private static final String ACTION = "com.app.services.UpdateDatabaseService";
    public static final String ACTION_TASK_1 = ACTION + ".latestChapters";
    public static final String ACTION_TASK_2 = ACTION + ".latestMangas";

    private static final byte PARALLELTASKS = 2;

    public LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PARALLELTASKS);

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public UpdateDatabaseService getService() {
            return UpdateDatabaseService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        // By default always it does DefaultTask1
        tasks.put(new DefaultTask1());

        if(!isEmptyTable("tableFoo")){
            tasks.put(new DefaultTask2());
        }

        executor();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action == ACTION_TASK_1){
                        tasks.put(new Task1());
            } else
            if(action == ACTION_TASK_2){
                tasks.put(new Task2());
            } 
        }


        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
            // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void executor(){

        while(true){    
                executor.execute(tasks.take());

    }


}
```

Comment: Post what code you can from your service, there is nothing here that will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Every process has a main application (UI) thread. It is the thread that calls your component lifecycle methods, such as `onStartCommand()` of a `Service`. And, you cannot tie up that thread, or you will get an ANR.

Normally, this is not a problem with an `IntentService`. No `IntentService` subclass should be creating its own threads, so there are only two threads of importance: the main application thread, and the `IntentService`-supplied background thread (the one that calls `onHandleIntent()`). Ensure that all your work is in `onHandleIntent()`. If you are forking additional threads on your own, either get rid of them, or switch from an `IntentService` to a regular `Service`, so that you can arrange for the `Service` to shut down only when *all* your threads are done with their work, instead of when `onHandleIntent()` is done.

Also, I strongly recommend that you get rid of the `android:process`, as you are wasting CPU and RAM for no obvious added benefit to the user.

Comment: An usefull explanation. I add some code and information about this issue (Edit 1) because I need this process for populate the app's database and then the service will manage update database with internet resources. I think this is benefit to user, and only critical first case.

Comment: @Franb: "This service has its own process because although the service catch the exceptions that could be to occur, this way the app is robuster against internet or parser failures (the app won't crash)" -- that is not a valid reason to have multiple processes in a resource-constrained environment, like a mobile device. Again, you are wasting RAM, CPU, and battery.

Comment: So, when do you use a separate process instead of a thread? or Which are the cases where is a good-practises use a process?

Comment: @Franb: "Which are the cases where is a good-practises use a process?" -- I cannot think of any. Any case where people use it could be handled in other ways without needing the second process. For example, some people use it to get more heap space on Android 1.x/2.x, but you could use the NDK for a similar purpose.